# How can I concatenate one column based on whether or not their is duplicate values in another column and add their quantity column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**The Problem**

I am trying to find a way to simplify data in multiple columns. Some columns have duplicate **COLOUR** values with a unique **ID** and a corresponding **QTY**. The ideal result would be a concatenated **ID** (based on duplicates), a sum of the **QTY** (based on duplicates) and consolidation of **COLOUR** (removing duplicates). Everything I have found so far doesn't quite fit the scenario and the expected outcome in the table below. Whatever the solution may be, there will be hundreds of unique entries in the **ID** column and **COLOUR** column so the solution must take that into consideration. Any help would be appreciated.

**Sample Data**

| ID | COLOUR | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | BLUE | 1 |
| B1 | GREEN | 2 |
| A2 | BLUE | 1 |
| A3 | BLUE | 1 |
| B2 | GREEN | 1 |

**Expected Outcome**

| ID | COLOUR | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1, A2, A3 | BLUE | 3 |
| B1, B2 | GREEN | 3 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, assuming you are using `MS365` then you may try using the formula as shown below,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=LET(U,UNIQUE(B2:B6),CHOOSE({1,2,3},
BYROW(U,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(A2:A6,a=B2:B6,"")))),
U,BYROW(U,LAMBDA(a,SUM(FILTER(C2:C6,a=B2:B6,""))))))
```

---

Also when writing this formula, if you are on `MS365` and have enabled the `Beta Channel` then using `VSTACK()` & `HSTACK()`

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `I1`

```
=LET(U,UNIQUE(B2:B6),VSTACK(A1:C1,HSTACK(
BYROW(U,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(A2:A6,a=B2:B6,"")))),
U,BYROW(U,LAMBDA(a,SUM(FILTER(C2:C6,a=B2:B6,"")))))))
```

---

Or, you can follow as **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir has mentioned, simplifying the formula by removing the 2nd `BYROW()` with `SUMIF()`

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=LET(X,UNIQUE(B2:B6),CHOOSE({1,2,3},BYROW(X,LAMBDA(a,
TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(A2:A6,B2:B6=a)))),X,SUMIF(B2:B6,X,C2:C6)))
```

---

Comment: I nearly had the same answer as you. I deleted mine. You can simplify your formula and remove the 2nd `BYROW()` >> `=LET(X,UNIQUE(B2:B6),CHOOSE({1,2,3},BYROW(X,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(A2:A6,B2:B6=a)))),X,SUMIF(B2:B6,X,C2:C6)))`

Comment: Sir sorry for the delay in response. Will do it. Not in front of the computer. If you wish you can edit the answer

Comment: Excellent answers. This worked as expected. Responses were very much appreciated. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Onyx87 glad to know it worked for you. =)